# Why this representation of circle is valid?

Tags: determinant

A line passing through two distinct points $P_1(x_1,y_1),P_2(x_2,y_2)$ can be expressed by 
$$\det\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
x-x_1&y-y_1 \\
x_2-x_1&y_2-y_1 \\ \end{array} \right|=0$$

Since line is set $A=\{a P_1+bP_2|a+b=1\}$ and it corresponds to determinant properties.

A circle passing three(non-colinear) points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$ can be expressed by $$\det\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2 & (x-x_1) & (y-y_1) \\
(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2 & (x_2-x_1) & (y_2-y_1) \\
(x_3-x_1)^2+(y_3-y_1)^2 & (x_3-x_1) & (y_3-y_1) \end{array} \right|=0$$
or $$\det\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
x^2+y^2 & x & y&1 \\
x_1^2+y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1&1 \\
x_2^2+y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2&1 \\
x_3^2+y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3&1 \\ \end{array} \right|=0$$

Please explain simple and neat as possible(like in determinant sense).

Comment: For the first one, when the determinant is $0$, that means the first row vector is parallel to the surface formed by the second and third row vectors. It means that $v_1=t v_2+(1-t)v_3$ for $(0\leq t\leq 1)$, where $v_i$ indicates the $i$-th row vector. Or just use David's idea mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consier the set of equations $$Ax^2+Ay^2+Bx+Cy+D=0  \tag{1} $$ 
$$Ax_1^2+Ay_1^2+Bx_1+Cy_1+D=0 \tag{2} $$
$$Ax_2^2+Ay_2^2+Bx_2+Cy_2+D=0 \tag{3} $$
$$Ax_3^2+Ay_3^2+Bx_3+Cy_3+D=0 \tag{4} $$
this is a $4\times4$ linear system and it must satisfy,
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x^2+y^2 & x & y&1 \\
x_1^2+y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1&1 \\
x_2^2+y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2&1 \\
x_3^2+y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3&1 \\ \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
A\\
B \\
C \\
D \\ \end{array} \right)=0 \tag{5}$$
taking determinant you get your required condition. Also you can subtract the set of equations $1\to 4$ to reduce it into $3\times 3$ system and get the other result.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** for the $4\times4$ version.

- Explain why expanding the determinant gives an equation of the form
  $$Ax^2+Ay^2+Bx+Cy+D=0\ ,$$
  where $A,B,C,D$ are constants.
- Explain why $A\ne0$.
- Explain why the three given points satisfy the equation.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow!!!!  I have never got two upvotes **and** two downvotes so quickly!  Would anyone care to explain?

Comment: i'll make it $4-2$ then